# How to avoid file corruption upon power shortage

Tags: windows-7, corruption

I have an industrial PC (Windows posready 7) running a server application that was corrupting files too often when the pc was abruptly turned off (power shortage) and I found that changing my code to set the FILE_WRITE_THROUGH flag solved the problem when the file was written by my application.

The problem is that when I copy+paste some file in the system, wait 5 seconds, then power off (unplug) the machine, the files are still always getting corrupted, by opening the corrupted files in an hex editor, I can see that from half of the file on, all its bytes were set to 0.

Is there a way to prevent this effect? Is it possible to change the default value for FILE_WRITE_THROUGH at system level so that all file operations start behaving like my application?

Comment: Why not plug the computer into a UPS so that, when the power turns off, the computer stays turned on?

Comment: How about using an UPS for the desktop or using a notebook?

Comment: Use a database with a write-ahead log. Or a drive controller or drive with a  write-cache battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from installing a UPS (which you really *should*), there is a setting you can use to tell the system to make sure everything is immediately written to disk instead of being kept in the system cache:

[image: Disable write caching]

Of course, disabling disk caching will reduce system performance. But f.e. it's automatically done by Windows on domain controllers, which absolutely ***must*** make a sure a directory update is actually written to the AD database when a DC thinks it is.

Comment: "tell the system to make sure everything is immediately written to disk instead of being kept in the system cache" This is exactly what I want to achieve, however, this solution didn't work for me and I have no idea why. In my tests, I got files being corrupted when the machine was reset 15 secs after the files were written

Comment: Then it could depend on the disk controller; some controllers have built-in caching. They also have management tools (either installable in the OS or at the very least in the system BIOS) to configure RAID, caching and whatever else.

Comment: Or use a drive controller or drive that has a write-buffer battery / capacitor

Answer (score 4):

Purchase a UPS for this system and install/configure the included software to perform a graceful shutdown of the system upon failure. This will prevent the issues you're having along with many others.